# How to specify blur event in angular js

Tags: angularjs, blur

I have a input text box and i want when user enter the value in text box and loses the focus. I want to validate this value from api values and need to show the appropriate message below the input box. How can i do in angular js

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive.

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="ValidateBlur()" />
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/hy2sCVjvVqBrm1WSdiBl?p=preview

**Module/Controller Setup code:**

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller("DarrenController", function($scope) {
    $scope.Text = "Testing...";

    $scope.ValidateBlur = function() {
      alert('Validating');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="DarrenController">
       <input type="text" ng-blur="ValidateBlur()" />
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: looks ok but how can i show the custom message for validation like if the user type something then if he deletes and loses focus i need to show the validation message- field is empty. and if he enters the value and it didn't match the values in the db values then i need to show -"the value doesn't  exist in database ".

Comment: @user3395635 - angular has a $http service so if your API is REST you could use this service to connect and bring back the database values and pass them to the validation method. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

//HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search ... " ng-focus="focusMsg()" ng-blur="blurMsg()">
```

// Controller

```
  $scope.focusMsg = function () {
            console.log('Focus');
        }

  $scope.blurMsg = function () {
            console.log('Blur');
        }
```